# Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm in javascript, modern and inside-out versions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shuffle

I've implemented two different versions of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) in javascript, and I'd like to know if I've made any mistakes.

I'm creating a deck of playing cards. I'm interested in these shuffle algorithms.

The object passed to the `rng` parameters below is a wrapper for [Johannes Baagøe's Alea](https://gist.github.com/1342599), a seedable PRNG that should produce a better sample of random numbers than built-in `Math.random`. Its API is the same as that of `Math.random`.

I am mostly wondering if I have made any fencepost errors or misunderstood the examples I'm referencing.

```
/** shuffle

    Shuffle an array. 

    @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm

    @param {Array} array
    @param {Function} random Optional RNG. Defaults to Math.random.
    @return {Array} The original array, shuffled.
*/
function shuffle (array, random) {
  var i = array.length, j, swap;
  while (--i) {
    j = (random ? random() : Math.random()) * (i + 1) | 0;
    swap = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = swap;
  }
  return array;
}

/** pushRand

    Insert a value into an array at a random index. The element 
    previously at that index will be pushed back onto the end. 

    @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm

    @param {Array} object to shuffle.
    @param {Mixed} value to insert.
    @param {Function} optional RNG. Defaults to Math.random.
    @return {Number} The new length of the array.

*/
function pushRand (array, value, random) {
  var j = (random ? random() : Math.random()) * array.length | 0;
  array.push(array[j]);
  array[j] = value;
  return array.length;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/ujahar/3/) of the shuffle. Reloading the page does the inside-out shuffle, and clicking the face-down card does the modern shuffle.

---

Edit: I found a fencepost error in the "modern" version and fixed it here, but it's still in the demo. Not sure about the "inside-out" version yet.

---

Edit: I stopped being lazy and factored this stuff out, so it should easier to look at now. New demo up.

---

Edit: inside-out ver had the fencepost error too. It should look like this, I think:

```
function pushRand (array, value, random) {
  var j = (random ? random() : Math.random()) * (array.length + 1) | 0;
  array.push(array[j]);
  array[j] = value;
  return array.length;
}
```

Thanks, Paul!

---

Edit: Taking Adam's optimization suggestion into account, the new code looks like this:

```
/** shuffle

    Shuffle an array. 

    @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm

    @param {Array} array Array to shuffle.
    @param {Object} rng Optional RNG. Defaults to Math.
    @return {Array} The original array, shuffled.
*/
function shuffle (array, rng) {
  var i = array.length, j, swap;
  if (!rng) rng = Math;
  while (--i) {
    j = rng.random() * (i + 1) | 0;
    swap = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = swap;
  }
  return array;
}

/** pushRand

    Insert a value into an array at a random index. The element 
    previously at that index will be pushed back onto the end. 

    @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm

    @param {Array} array Array to insert into.
    @param {Mixed} value Value to insert.
    @param {Object} rng Optional RNG. Defaults to Math.
    @return {Number} The new length of the array.

*/
function pushRand (array, value, rng) {
  var j = (rng || Math).random() * (array.length + 1) | 0;
  array.push(array[j]);
  array[j] = value;
  return array.length;
}
```

Here's the [updated editable demo](http://jsbin.com/ujahar/5/edit) (relevant code at the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you modify the inside out code to scale by `(index+1)`

```
       randomIndex = rand()*(index+1)|0;
```

You will not be covering all the possibilities.
For `index == 0`, you always generate 0 -- this is correct, but only by accident.

For `index == 1`, you also always generate 0 -- instead of a 50/50 split between 0 and 1

The second card in the deck misses its ONLY chance to get to be `card[1]`.

The same problem continues for each card from then on, without the `+1`, `randomIndex < index`  when you want `randomIndex <= index`.

The problem may be even clearer for the last card placed in the deck. For a 52 card deck, `index == 51`, so `randomIndex` can be at most 50. So any prior card has a possibility of ending up at card[51], but not the last card. It can get no closer than card[50].

It should be reassuring that this change makes the math for the initial shuffle look more like that of the re-shuffle.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I edited my code while you were writing that. I had a feeling this might be the case, was just off to write a test harness to check the random distribution. So in the new code (second function), `array.length` should be `(array.length + 1)`, correct?

Comment: I reviewed the unfactored version. I'm pretty sure the same bug still lurks. Also, the new code seems weird: Is it a safe no-op to `array.push(array[0])` on an empty array?

Comment: yeah that part's safe, if you click the demo and then click the thing in the upper right hand corner you can edit the code live, shuffle stuff is at the bottom

Comment: So, it seems that `array.push(array[j])` is safe even accounting for the possibility of `j == array.length` -- it's just a little wierd. It's exactly the "completely safe assignment from uninitialized data" that the Wikipedia article warns about, but it gets a little confusing when you try to think of push as growing the array to include the exact non-pre-existent element that is being provided as its initializer.

Comment: I've come back to look at it three times to make sure the push wasn't messing things up, but since it always happens first it's safe... yeah this is the thing the article warns (or "unwarns?") about

Comment: @PaulMartel, Could you please tell me which one you think is better for shuffeling? (Link: http://ideone.com/pfRanN). As i tested, there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can optimize the first line inside the while loop:

```
 function shuffle (array, random) {
    var i = array.length, j, swap;
    while (--i) {
      j = (random ? random() : Math.random()) * (i + 1) | 0;
```

The check for random's boolean value happens each time (depending on the compiler, I imagine some optimize around it nicely). It's likely to run a bit faster like this:

```
 function shuffle (array, random) {
    var i = array.length, j, swap;
    random = random || Math.random;
    while (--i) {
      j = random() * (i + 1) | 0;
```

**Edit**: had `random |=` incorrectly (which does *binary* OR) - replaced with `random = random ||`

Comment: Is it always safe to detach `random` from `Math` like that? I'm wary of getting references to built-in functions. I feel like some implementation might need its `this` reference or something.

Comment: Good question! I take functions as objects so blindly I had to do some research for the special `Math` object. I'm going to have to say yes: [Here's an example](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/) where John Resig treats them directly as "normal" functions.

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of my question. I feel like this is probably safe in practice but i suspect that by definition it might be undefined behavior. I worked around it by changing the api to require an object with a `random` function property instead of a function.

Comment: of course pushRand could probably be further optimized by doing something like `pushRand.generator = rng` before calling it instead of passing it in every time, but I'd just as soon come up with a better api altogether

Comment: Well, I searched various compiled js sources (google websites, jquery-min, etc) and I couldn't find an instance where even those people used the `Math` methods any other way than "normally", so I'm not sure if there's really any risk or not. I think for the `Math` object you're safe, but others might have issues like you describe. That said, running this works fine in Chrome: `var x = Math.random; alert(x());`

Comment: I had to look around a bit, but [this seems relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work). I think it's best practice not to detach native functions, even if it's safe sometimes. `random |= Math.random` doesn't seem to work btw: `var foo = 4; foo |= 5; console.log(foo) // 5`

Comment: I'll agree with that - I can't find any case where the `Math` methods are detached in the field other than old `with(Math)` examples, but I do know those functions are "static" in the sense that clearly they don't care too much about their scope since their scope is just the `Math` object. Hmm, unless one of them was written to call something else on `Math` relatively rather than statically, like `Math.tan = function(a) { return this.sin(a) / this.cos(a); };` - but I'd be disappointed if that actually happens anywhere.